# How to enable wysiwyg editor for custom attribute in admin category page?

Tags: category, magento-enterprise, magento2.4.6, category-attribute

I have created a custom category attribute using below code.

**Ayakil\CustomCategoryAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data\AddMyDescriptionCategoryAttribute.php**

```
public function apply()
{
    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'my_description',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'my_description',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'sort_order' => 444,
            'source' => '',
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => null,
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'backend' => '',
            'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
            'is_wysiwyg_enabled'  => true,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
        ]
    );

    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
}
```

**Ayakil\CustomCategoryAttribute\view\admin_html\ui_component\category_form.xml**

```
<field name="my_description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="150" formElement="wysiwyg">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">My Description</label>
            <notice translate="true">Note: Keyboard shortcut to activate editor help : Alt + 0 (Windows) or &#x2325;0 (MacOS)</notice>
            <dataScope>my_description</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                <settings>
                    <rows>8</rows>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

This will add the My description field in category as below
[image]

But when i go to the **Schedule Changes** and clic **Schedule New Update** Button i'm not getting the wysiwyg editor there.
[image]

Can anyone please tell me what i am missing here.

Comment: I will edit your code and get the final solution you need. so please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a similar way in the content staging form. You can see the layout here **vendor/magento/module-catalog-staging/view/adminhtml/ui_component/catalogstaging_category_update_form.xml**

Follow the default description settings in this xml like:

```
<field name="description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="50" formElement="wysiwyg">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Description</label>
        <dataScope>description</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
            <settings>
                <rows>8</rows>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

So create file (view/adminhtml/ui_component/catalogstaging_category_update_form.xml) inside your module and add your custom attribute config.

Comment: Thank you, Its worked like charm,

Answer (score 1):

Hello dear I will add your code my project when I get the final solution.  i will change my code. you can read and follow all the steps.

Go directory to app/code/Test/Uiform\Setup\Patch\Data\AddMyDescriptionCategoryAttribute

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Uiform\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddMyDescriptionCategoryAttribute implements DataPatchInterface,   PatchRevertableInterface
{

/**
 * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
 */
private $moduleDataSetup;
/**
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
) {
    $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function apply()
{
    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'my_description',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'my_description',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'sort_order' => 333,
            'source' => '',
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => null,
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'backend' => ''
        ]
    );

    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
}

public function revert()
{
    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
    $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'my_description');

    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getAliases()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [
    
    ];
}
 }
```

after go to /var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Uiform/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

<fieldset name="content">
    <field name="my_description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="50" formElement="wysiwyg">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">My Description</label>
            <notice translate="true">Note: Keyboard shortcut to activate editor help : Alt + 0 (Windows) or &#x2325;0 (MacOS)</notice>
            <dataScope>my_description</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                <settings>
                    <rows>8</rows>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

after apply below  commands

```
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated
```

Please check my below screen shot.

[image]
[image]

I hope that you understand solved this issue. after my code implementation solved the issue then accept my answer and upvote.

Comment: Thanks,  My version is EE, there is a schedule update part and my issue was that wyswyg editor is not appearing there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="my_description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="150" formElement="wysiwyg">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">My Description</label>
        <notice translate="true">Note: Keyboard shortcut to activate editor help : Alt + 0 (Windows) or &#x2325;0 (MacOS)</notice>
        <dataScope>my_description</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
            <settings>
                <rows>8</rows>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Here dear you can try this.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer my question, Your answer not giving any information to fix my issue

Comment: i will share my latest code with implementation my project so please check this.